# publish to android node

Tags: roscore, rosjava, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I have installed the android_tutorial_pubsub on android device and able to connect to roscore on my computer (I see the chatter topic in the topic lists). I run a Talker node on my computer and see the data publish to the chatter topic correctly. However, the rosTextView node on my android device doesnt show anything.

Do you know how to publish data to a node on android device?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59656/publish-to-android-node/) by [Gosu](https://answers.ros.org/users/4354/gosu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 22 on 2013-03-31

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PeterMilani](https://answers.ros.org/users/3621/petermilani/) on 2013-04-02**:
can you run rxgraph and see that both your rosTextView  and talker node both appear?

**Comment by [Gosu](https://answers.ros.org/users/4354/gosu/) on 2013-04-04**:
Yes, both the node appear, but my talker node only publish to /rostopic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In android_tutorial_pubsub, the NodeConfiguration is private. Nodes on your PC will not be able to communicate with those on your Android device.

Try changing the [NodeConfiguration](http://docs.rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/rosjava_core/html/javadoc/org/ros/node/NodeConfiguration.html) to a public one. See the NodeConfiguration.newPublic documentation.

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2013-04-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Gosu](https://answers.ros.org/users/4354/gosu/) on 2013-04-04**:
I have tried but no luck, the rosTextView node still doesnt receive anything

**Comment by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) on 2013-04-04**:
Check your ROS_IP and ROS_MASTER_URI settings. Also check the host string you're using in your NodeConfiguration.

**Comment by [Gosu](https://answers.ros.org/users/4354/gosu/) on 2013-04-04**:
Thank you very much! Its worked! I forgot to set ROS_IP and ROS_MASTER_URI variables